# I'm using Winwheel.js to create a roulette. Is there a way to insert prize image in a segment without using the one image per segment?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make the segments dynamic by adding or removing a segment. If I use the one segment per image, i also need to update the image of every segment.

Is there a way to insert prize image in a segment without using the one image per segment?

Comment: Can you add some code so we can see what you're trying to accomplish?